# How long does it take to start sweet potato slips?

Tags: vegetables, root-vegetables, seed-starting, sweet-potato

@Om Patange asked this in a comment on [this sweet potato question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/how-can-i-grow-my-own-sweet-potato-starts) and I'm curious about the answer:

> How long does each step [in starting sweet potato slips] take? I ask to know how long before spring I should start the process so that I have healthy slips to put in the ground. Also, when is a good time to plant the slips in the ground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zone 7-8 Sweet Potaoes go in around June 1 or after.  The time depends how many steps you are doing.  We started with organic potatos from organic grocery store, cut up and planted those to make sprouts, that was about 3-4 weeks.  Then we cut vines off those sprouts, placed in buckets of water outdoors 2 weeks or so, then planted each of those rooted slips in the field rows.  The whole process only took about 6 weeks.