# How to grow leaves from a sweet potato (not in a jar of water)?

Tags: growth, sweet-potato, humidity

I once accidentally grew sweet potatos in my kitchen - it was just sitting there for a while since I haven't used it, without rotting, and it started growing.

I'm trying to reproduce it, because I liked the result (the old ones died when I wasn't at home for a few weeks) - but no luck.

I guess they were growing and surviving from the vapor and humidity in the kitchen.

What should I do to reproduce it?

I saw [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/how-can-i-grow-my-own-sweet-potato-starts) regards how to grow it in water - but it's not what I'm looking for.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I started mine by carefully cutting out the slips and planting them outside.

You could the same thing in a pot. Just keep it moist until it takes hold.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually wanted to reproduce what I did in the past :)